# make location fields made visible in solr

Tags: solr, location, store

I have the following field defined in solr (schema.xml)

```
<field name="store" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

If I search for say this-

```
&fq={!geofilt pt=45.15,-93.85 sfield=store d=5}
```

Then I can see the location coordinates in the search result.

But the field "store" seems to be a hidden field under normal circumstances. How do I get the coordinates to be a part of the search result for normal searches? (q=*:* for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just verified that this works correctly for both Solr 3.1 and Solr 4.0-dev with the example data.

Example:
[http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&fl=id,store&wt=json&indent=true](http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=%2a%3a%2a&fl=id,store&wt=json&indent=true)

```
[...]
      "response":{"numFound":17,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"SP2514N",
        "store":"35.0752,-97.032"},
      {
        "id":"6H500F0",
        "store":"45.17614,-93.87341"},
      {
        "id":"F8V7067-APL-KIT",
        "store":"45.18014,-93.87741"},
[...]
```

Did you perhaps change this setting and forget to re-index or forget to commit?

Comment: +1, Had the same thought: 1. restart solr 2. reindex 3. commit